# VMware tools are not compatible with Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: vmware-player, ubuntu-11.04

I upgraded Ubuntu to the latest version (11.04) on VMware 7 with a lot of effort to boot the virtual computer from [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) CLI. Then I reinstalled the VMware tools again since I couldn't run Unity Mode.

However, they are not compatible. When I enter the Ubuntu system in GNOME classic, I can only see a part of the screen which means the bar at the bottom disappears.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You can wait til they release a new version of vmware tools...

Comment: Or you can just install the latest VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

See *[VMware-player on Ubuntu 11.04 kernel 2.6.38-8](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/312086?tstart=0)*.

Download the patch, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That thread appears to be about installing VMware Player *in* Ubuntu and not about installing Ubuntu 11.04 *within* VMware [Workstation/Player].

Comment: I adjust the resolution and can see the bottom bar though I cannot enable full screen mode. And I run the following commands to start up Unity Theme(found at: http://www.macheist.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=19265)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-2d-default-settings
I think I could only to wait new version of vmware tools to solve the compatible problem completely:(